# Valores 1/0 a Si/No en dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql

Este formulario te permite modificar un curso, tiene una opción que dice *VISIBLE*. En esta opción se verifica con 0 (no) y con 1 (si). Lo que estoy intnentando de lograr es que solo puedan selecionar 1 o 0 y que en el dropdown tenga un texto en vez de un numero (1 = Si y 0 = No).

Si se crea un curso nuevo se puede poner un:

```
<select name="visible" id="visible">
<option value="1">Si</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

La parte dificil es que tome los datos que ya tenia este curso. Si la opcion *visible* estaba en 0 o en 1, y si estaba en 1 entonces la siguiente opcion deberia ser 0.

Con un input funciona, el problema es que pueden poner cualquier numero, la intencion es que el usuario tenga un texto en vez de un 1 y 0 por que no saben que numero significa cada cosa.

```
<?php
  require 'config/config.php';
  require 'funciones/autenticar.php';
  autenticar();
  require 'funciones/conexion.php'; 
  require 'funciones/cursada.php';
  $cursadas = verCursadaPorID();
  $visible2 = $cursadas['visible'];
?>

<main class="container">
    <h1>Modificar curso</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-secondary p-4 col-8">
        <form method="post" action="modificarCurso.php">
                            
                ID cursada:<br>
            <input type="text" readonly name="id_cursada" value="<?= $cursadas['id_cursada'] ?>" ><br>

                Nombre:<br>
            <input type="text" readonly name="nombre" value="<?= $cursadas['nombre'] ?>" required><br>
            
                Fecha de inicio:<br>
            <input type="text" name="fechaini" value="<?= $cursadas['fechaini'] ?>" required><br>

        Visible:<br>
            <select name="visible" id="visible">
                <option value="<?php $cursadas['visible']?>"><?php echo ''.(boolval(0) ? 'Si' : 'No')."\n";  ?></option>
            </select>
            

            <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Guardar cambios</button>
            <a href="panelAdmin.php" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Cancelar</a>

        </form>
    </div>

</main>
```

Por el momento este codigo te muestra la opcion que ya tenia pero no muestra la segunda opcion *(Falta la otra opcion que seria 1 - Si)*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no pones agregas a tu codigo la opcion de que ya tenia como selected y el otro lo dejas normal

Comment: Por que va cambiando acorde a lo que el usuario seleccione. Si selecciona que SI y luego guarda. El `selected` tendria que ser SI. Si selecciona que NO y luego guarda. El `selected` tendria que ser NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se si la propiedad selected tiene el comportamiento que buscas

```html
<div>
<label>Predeterminado SI</label>
<br/>
<select name="visible" id="visible">
    <option value="1" selected>Si</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<label>Predeterminado NO</label>
<br/>
<select name="visible" id="visible">
    <option value="1">Si</option>
    <option value="0" selected>No</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Puedes poner las dos opciones y validarlas para que seleccione la actual con la propiedad **selected**. Algo así

```
Visible:<br>
<select name="visible" id="visible">
    <option value="1" <?php echo $cursadas['visible']==1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Si</option>
    <option value="0" <?php echo $cursadas['visible']==0 ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: El problema de este codigo es que te pone como predeterminado la primera opcion, que es SI. En vez de dejar seleccionado la opcion que ya tiene guardado.  Por ejemplo: Lo probe con uno que tiene la opcion 0 - NO, y al querer editarlo, te auto selecciona la opcion SI. Tendria que seleccionar la opcion que tiene guardado en la base de datos.

Comment: Puede que tenga que hay un detalle en la validación, no se si necesariamente $cursadas['visible'] contenga valor de 1 o 0 en ese momento, pero la propiedad selected le indica a la lista cual opción debe estar seleccionada al momento de cargar el documento. Edité la respuesta para ver si es comportamiento que buscas

Comment: No, sigue sin servir. Igual gracias Abraham.  Si el usuario selecciona que SI y luego guarda. El selected tendria que ser SI. Si el usuarijo selecciona que NO y luego guarda. El selected tendria que ser NO.

Comment: @Cloby Ese codigo deberia funcionarte si la variable `visible` toma siempre el ultimo valor guardado

Comment: Ahi funciona! Muchas gracias